# log4net capturing errors without try-catch

Tags: log4net

Typically we would do this, to capture exceptions into our log files:

```
try
{
     Method1();
     Method2();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     log.Error(ex.Message);
}
```

Is there a way, without using even try-catch, to capture errors?

Comment: [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might be of interest to you. If using a web framework, there is likely some kind of similar catch-all error method; e.g., ASP.NET has [`Application_Error`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you have to make changes in Global.asax file

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));

    void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

        log.Error("App_Error", ex);
    }


    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    }

}
```

Comment: What if your application is not asp.net? but command line program or window services.

Comment: In 2.0 also you have applicaiton_error event, make changes in Global.ascx file

Comment: For more info refer this http://ruchirac.blogspot.com/2012/10/configure-log4net-with-aspnet-logging.html